# Checking if device is iPad

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

What is wrong with this code? I want to be able to check if the current device the user is using is an iPad but it keeps giving me errors.

```
if (UIUserInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
{
    //do stuff
}
```

Comment: You probably want to tag this with more than just ipad.

Comment: Maybe you're calling it too late? Are you loading your XIB manually? I remember doing this and succeeding. But I guess there are better solutions.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can use

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
```

Comment: Note that an UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone value does not necessarily mean that you're on an iPhone device - rather, that the interface idiom matches the iPhone one. You might be on an iPad, running an iPhone-only app in 1x/2x mode.

Comment: Actually it's UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM().

Comment: That's an interesting point magma thanks for bringing it to my attention. I had no idea that was the case

Answer (score 43):

In Swift you can use:

```
if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad {
    //do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 7):

you must cheack the condition wheather device is iphone/ipad

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
    {
//do ur  ipad logic
}else
{
//do ur  iphone logic
}
```

Answer (score 5):

> /* The UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() function is provided for use when deploying to a version of the iOS less than 3.2. If the earliest version of iPhone/iOS that you will be deploying for is 3.2 or greater, you may use -[UIDevice userInterfaceIdiom] directly.
>    */

Better use `UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom` unless you are supporting super old iOS.

Possible cases are as below:

```
public enum UIUserInterfaceIdiom : Int {
    case unspecified

    @available(iOS 3.2, *)
    case phone // iPhone and iPod touch style UI

    @available(iOS 3.2, *)
    case pad // iPad style UI

    @available(iOS 9.0, *)
    case tv // Apple TV style UI

    @available(iOS 9.0, *)
    case carPlay // CarPlay style UI
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are using swift, use this

```
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.Pad)
    {
      // device is ipad
    }
    else
    {
        //  device is iPhone
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

My app runs as an iPhone only app on iPad, but I still needed to detect if the device is iPad to hide certain features in the app that relate to the Apple HealthKit, which is not available on iPads. I used this approach instead.

```
extension UIDevice {
    var isPad: Bool {
        get {
            return UIDevice.deviceInfo.lowercased().containsWord("ipados")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OBJC:

```
if (UIDevice.currentDevice.userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad){
        //do awesome objc stuff!;
    }
```